# Property Gets The Default Value After Calling PropertyInfo.SetValue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, reflection

I am using reflection to set a value of a property, but it is not working! this is because the default color is resetting after! That's is my code:

MapWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MapRepresentation.MapWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MapWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid Width="640" Height="739">
        <Path x:Name="akkar" Data="..." HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="124.318" Margin="0,6.482,82.619,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211.881" /> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MapWindow.Xaml.cs:

```
public Brush AkkarColor  
{  
    get { return this.akkar.Fill; }
    set { this.akkar.Fill = value; }
}

public void ChangeColor()
{  
    Type type = GetType();
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    PropertyInfo pathInfo = type.GetProperty("AkkarColor");
    pathInfo.SetValue(obj, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red, null);
}

private void akkar_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  
    ChangeColor();
}
```

what is wrong ? why the color of the path Akkar is not changing?

Comment: Why are you doing this via reflection? There is an much easier way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are creating a new instance of the `MapWindow`. Pass `this` to `SetValue`.

```
public void ChangeColor()  
{  
   Type type = GetType();  
    PropertyInfo pathInfo = type.GetProperty("AkkarColor");  
    pathInfo.SetValue(this, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red, null);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new instance of the current type, setting a property on it, and then ignoring the newly created object. I suspect you want to change the property on the *current* object, i.e.

```
// Remove the line declaring and initializing obj
pathInfo.SetValue(this, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red, null);
```

Having said that, it's not at all clear why you're using reflection in the first place.